# Marshaling an IntPtr[] inside a struct causes midiStream functions to bug out, but unrolling the array to a bunch of fields works

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke, midi

I'm trying to use the Windows multimedia MIDI functions from C#. Specifically:

```
MMRESULT midiOutPrepareHeader(  HMIDIOUT hmo,  LPMIDIHDR lpMidiOutHdr,  UINT cbMidiOutHdr  );
MMRESULT midiOutUnprepareHeader(  HMIDIOUT hmo,  LPMIDIHDR lpMidiOutHdr,  UINT cbMidiOutHdr  );
MMRESULT midiStreamOut(  HMIDISTRM hMidiStream,  LPMIDIHDR lpMidiHdr,  UINT cbMidiHdr  );
MMRESULT midiStreamRestart(  HMIDISTRM hms  );

/* MIDI data block header */
typedef struct midihdr_tag {
    LPSTR       lpData;               /* pointer to locked data block */
    DWORD       dwBufferLength;       /* length of data in data block */
    DWORD       dwBytesRecorded;      /* used for input only */
    DWORD_PTR   dwUser;               /* for client's use */
    DWORD       dwFlags;              /* assorted flags (see defines) */
    struct midihdr_tag far *lpNext;   /* reserved for driver */
    DWORD_PTR   reserved;             /* reserved for driver */
#if (WINVER >= 0x0400)
    DWORD       dwOffset;             /* Callback offset into buffer */
    DWORD_PTR   dwReserved[8];        /* Reserved for MMSYSTEM */
#endif
} MIDIHDR, *PMIDIHDR, NEAR *NPMIDIHDR, FAR *LPMIDIHDR;
```

From a C program, I can successfully use these functions, by doing the following:

```
HMIDISTRM hms;
midiStreamOpen(&hms, ...);
MIDIHDR hdr;
hdr.this = that; ...

midiStreamRestart(hms);
midiOutPrepareHeader(hms, &hdr, sizeof(MIDIHDR)); // sizeof(MIDIHDR) == 64
midiStreamOut(hms, &hdr, sizeof(MIDIHDR));
// wait for an event that is set from the midi callback when the playback has finished
WaitForSingleObject(...);
midiOutUnprepareHeader(hms, &hdr, sizeof(MIDIHDR));
```

The above calling sequence works and produces no errors (error checks have been omitted for readability).

For the purpose of using those in C#, I have created some P/Invoke code:

```
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern int midiOutPrepareHeader(IntPtr handle, ref MidiHeader header, uint headerSize);
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern int midiOutUnprepareHeader(IntPtr handle, ref MidiHeader header, uint headerSize);
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern int midiStreamOut(IntPtr handle, ref MidiHeader header, uint headerSize);
[DllImport("winmm.dll")]
public static extern int midiStreamRestart(IntPtr handle);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct MidiHeader
{
    public IntPtr Data;
    public uint BufferLength;
    public uint BytesRecorded;
    public IntPtr UserData;
    public uint Flags;
    public IntPtr Next;
    public IntPtr Reserved;
    public uint Offset;

    //[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    //public IntPtr[] Reserved2;

    public IntPtr Reserved0;
    public IntPtr Reserved1;
    public IntPtr Reserved2;
    public IntPtr Reserved3;
    public IntPtr Reserved4;
    public IntPtr Reserved5;
    public IntPtr Reserved6;
    public IntPtr Reserved7;
}
```

The call sequence is the same as in C:

```
var hdr = new MidiHeader();
hdr.this = that;
midiStreamRestart(handle);
midiOutPrepareHeader(handle, ref header, headerSize); // headerSize == 64
midiStreamOut(handle, ref header, headerSize);
mre.WaitOne(); // wait until the midi playback has finished.
midiOutUnprepareHeader(handle, ref header, headerSize);
```

MIDI output works and the code produces no error (error checks are again omitted).

As soon as I uncomment the two lines with the array in `MidiHeader`, and instead remove the `Reserved0` to `Reserved7` fields, it doesn't work anymore. What happens is the following:

Everything is normal until and including `midiStreamOut`. I can hear the midi output. The playback length is correct. However, the event callback is never called when the playback ends.

At this point the value of `MidiHeader.Flags` is `0xe`, indicating that the stream is still playing (even though the callback has been notified with the message that playback has finished). The value of `MidiHeader.Flags` should be `9`, indicating that the stream has finished playing.

The call to `midiOutUnprepareHeader` fails with the error code `0x41` ("Cannot perform this operation while media data is still playing.  Reset the device, or wait until the data is finished playing."). Note that resetting the device, as suggested in the error message, does in fact not fix the problem (neither does waiting or trying it multiple times).

Another variant that works correctly is if I use `IntPtr` instead of `ref MidiHeader` in the signatures of the C# declarations, and then manually allocate unmanaged memory, copying my `MidiHeader` structure onto that memory, and then using the allocated memory to call the functions.

Furthermore, I tried decreasing the size I'm passing to the `headerSize` argument to 32. Since the fields are reserved (and, in fact, didn't exist in previous version of the Windows API), they seemed to have no particular purpose anyway. However, this does not fix the problem, even though Windows should not even know that the array exists, and therefore it should not do anything. Commenting out the array entirely yet again fixes the problem (i.e., both the array as well as the 8 `Reserved*` fields are commented out, and the `headerSize` is 32).

This hints to me that the `IntPtr[] Reserved2` cannot be marshaled correctly, and attempting to do so is corrupting other values. To verify that, I have created a Platform Invoke test project:

```
WIN32PROJECT1_API void __stdcall test_function(struct test_struct_t *s)
{
    printf("%u %u %u %u %u %u %u %u\n", s->test0, s->test1, s->test2, s->test3, s->test4, s->test5, s->test6, s->test7);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(s->pointer_array) / sizeof(s->pointer_array[0]); ++i)
    {
        printf("%u ", ((uint32_t)s->pointer_array[i]) >> 16);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

typedef int32_t *test_ptr;

struct test_struct_t
{
    test_ptr test0;
    uint32_t test1;
    uint32_t test2;
    test_ptr test3;
    uint32_t test4;
    test_ptr test5;
    uint32_t test6;
    uint32_t test7;
    test_ptr pointer_array[8];
};
```

Which is called from C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct TestStruct
{
    public IntPtr test0;
    public uint test1;
    public uint test2;
    public IntPtr test3;
    public uint test4;
    public IntPtr test5;
    public uint test6;
    public uint test7;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
    public IntPtr[] pointer_array;
}

[DllImport("Win32Project1.dll")]
static extern void test_function(ref TestStruct s);

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    TestStruct s = new TestStruct();
    s.test0 = IntPtr.Zero;
    s.test1 = 1;
    s.test2 = 2;
    s.test3 = IntPtr.Add(IntPtr.Zero, 3);
    s.test4 = 4;
    s.test5 = IntPtr.Add(IntPtr.Zero, 5);
    s.test6 = 6;
    s.test7 = 7;
    s.pointer_array = new IntPtr[8];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.pointer_array.Length; ++i)
    {
        s.pointer_array[i] = IntPtr.Add(IntPtr.Zero, i << 16);
    }
    test_function(ref s);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

And the output is as expected, hence the marshaling of the `IntPtr[] pointer_array` worked in this program.

*I am aware that not using `SafeHandle` is suboptimal, however, when using that, the behavior of the MIDI functions when using the array is even weirder, so I chose to maybe tackle one problem at a time.*

Why does using `IntPtr[] Reserved2` cause an error?

---

**Here is some more code to produce a complete example:**

C Code

```
/*
* example9.c
*
*  Created on: Dec 21, 2011
*      Author: David J. Rager
*       Email: djrager@fourthwoods.com
*
* This code is hereby released into the public domain per the Creative Commons
* Public Domain dedication.
*
* http://http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/
*/
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <stdio.h>

HANDLE event;

static void CALLBACK example9_callback(HMIDIOUT out, UINT msg, DWORD dwInstance, DWORD dwParam1, DWORD dwParam2)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case MOM_DONE:
        SetEvent(event);
        break;
    case MOM_POSITIONCB:
    case MOM_OPEN:
    case MOM_CLOSE:
        break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int streambufsize = 24;
    char* streambuf = NULL;

    HMIDISTRM out;
    MIDIPROPTIMEDIV prop;
    MIDIHDR mhdr;
    unsigned int device = 0;

    streambuf = (char*)malloc(streambufsize);
    if (streambuf == NULL)
        goto error2;

    memset(streambuf, 0, streambufsize);

    if ((event = CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0)) == NULL)
        goto error3;

    memset(&mhdr, 0, sizeof(mhdr));
    mhdr.lpData = streambuf;
    mhdr.dwBufferLength = mhdr.dwBytesRecorded = streambufsize;
    mhdr.dwFlags = 0;

    // flags and event code
    mhdr.lpData[8] = (char)0x90;
    mhdr.lpData[9] = 63;
    mhdr.lpData[10] = 0x55;
    mhdr.lpData[11] = 0;
    // next event
    mhdr.lpData[12] = 96; // delta time?
    mhdr.lpData[20] = (char)0x80;
    mhdr.lpData[21] = 63;
    mhdr.lpData[22] = 0x55;
    mhdr.lpData[23] = 0;


    if (midiStreamOpen(&out, &device, 1, (DWORD)example9_callback, 0, CALLBACK_FUNCTION) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
        goto error4;

    //printf("sizeof midiheader = %d\n", sizeof(MIDIHDR));

    if (midiOutPrepareHeader((HMIDIOUT)out, &mhdr, sizeof(MIDIHDR)) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
        goto error5;

    if (midiStreamRestart(out) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
        goto error6;

    if (midiStreamOut(out, &mhdr, sizeof(MIDIHDR)) != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
        goto error7;

    WaitForSingleObject(event, INFINITE);

error7:
    //midiOutReset((HMIDIOUT)out);

error6:
    MMRESULT blah = midiOutUnprepareHeader((HMIDIOUT)out, &mhdr, sizeof(MIDIHDR));

    printf("stuff: %d\n", blah);

error5:
    midiStreamClose(out);

error4:
    CloseHandle(event);

error3:
    free(streambuf);

error2:
    //free(tracks);

error1:
    //free(hdr);

    return(0);
}
```

C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace MidiOutTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int midiStreamOpen(out IntPtr handle, ref uint deviceId, uint cMidi, MidiCallback callback, IntPtr userData, uint flags);
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int midiStreamOut(IntPtr handle, ref MidiHeader header, uint headerSize);
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int midiStreamRestart(IntPtr handle);
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int midiOutPrepareHeader(IntPtr handle, ref MidiHeader header, uint headerSize);
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int midiOutUnprepareHeader(IntPtr handle, ref MidiHeader header, uint headerSize);
        [DllImport("winmm.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern int midiOutGetErrorText(int mmsyserr, StringBuilder errMsg, int capacity);
        [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        public static extern int midiStreamClose(IntPtr handle);

        public delegate void MidiCallback(IntPtr handle, uint msg, IntPtr instance, IntPtr param1, IntPtr param2);

        private static readonly ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

        private static void TestMidiCallback(IntPtr handle, uint msg, IntPtr instance, IntPtr param1, IntPtr param2)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(msg.ToString());
            if (msg == MOM_DONE)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("MOM_DONE");
                mre.Set();
            }
        }

        public const uint MOM_DONE = 0x3C9;
        public const int MMSYSERR_NOERROR = 0;
        public const int MAXERRORLENGTH = 256;
        public const uint CALLBACK_FUNCTION = 0x30000;
        public const uint MidiHeaderSize = 64;

        public static void CheckMidiOutMmsyserr(int mmsyserr)
        {
            if (mmsyserr != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
            {
                var sb = new StringBuilder(MAXERRORLENGTH);
                var errorResult = midiOutGetErrorText(mmsyserr, sb, sb.Capacity);
                if (errorResult != MMSYSERR_NOERROR)
                {
                    throw new /*Midi*/Exception("An error occurred and there was another error while attempting to retrieve the error message."/*, mmsyserr*/);
                }
                throw new /*Midi*/Exception(sb.ToString()/*, mmsyserr*/);
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntPtr handle;
            uint deviceId = 0;
            CheckMidiOutMmsyserr(midiStreamOpen(out handle, ref deviceId, 1, TestMidiCallback, IntPtr.Zero, CALLBACK_FUNCTION));
            try
            {
                var bytes = new byte[24];
                IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);

                try
                {
                    MidiHeader header = new MidiHeader();
                    header.Data = buffer;
                    header.BufferLength = 24;
                    header.BytesRecorded = 24;
                    header.UserData = IntPtr.Zero;
                    header.Flags = 0;
                    header.Next = IntPtr.Zero;
                    header.Reserved = IntPtr.Zero;
                    header.Offset = 0;
#warning uncomment if using array
                    //header.Reserved2 = new IntPtr[8];

                    // flags and event code
                    bytes[8] = 0x90;
                    bytes[9] = 63;
                    bytes[10] = 0x55;
                    bytes[11] = 0;
                    // next event
                    bytes[12] = 96;
                    bytes[20] = 0x80;
                    bytes[21] = 63;
                    bytes[22] = 0x55;
                    bytes[23] = 0;
                    Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, buffer, bytes.Length);

                    CheckMidiOutMmsyserr(midiStreamRestart(handle));
                    CheckMidiOutMmsyserr(midiOutPrepareHeader(handle, ref header, MidiHeaderSize));
                    CheckMidiOutMmsyserr(midiStreamOut(handle, ref header, MidiHeaderSize));
                    mre.WaitOne();
                    CheckMidiOutMmsyserr(midiOutUnprepareHeader(handle, ref header, MidiHeaderSize));
                }
                finally
                {
                    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                midiStreamClose(handle);
            }
        }
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MidiHeader
    {
        public IntPtr Data;
        public uint BufferLength;
        public uint BytesRecorded;
        public IntPtr UserData;
        public uint Flags;
        public IntPtr Next;
        public IntPtr Reserved;
        public uint Offset;
#if false
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 8)]
        public IntPtr[] Reserved2;
#else
        public IntPtr Reserved0;
        public IntPtr Reserved1;
        public IntPtr Reserved2;
        public IntPtr Reserved3;
        public IntPtr Reserved4;
        public IntPtr Reserved5;
        public IntPtr Reserved6;
        public IntPtr Reserved7;
#endif
    }
}
```

Comment: for an excellent question. If only they were all this good. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of `midiOutPrepareHeader`:

> Before you pass a MIDI data block to a device driver, you must prepare the buffer by passing it to the midiOutPrepareHeader function. After the header has been prepared, do not modify the buffer. After the driver is done using the buffer, call the midiOutUnprepareHeader function.

You are not adhering to this. The marshaller creates a temporary native version of your struct which lives for the duration of the call to `midiOutPrepareHeader`. Once `midiOutPrepareHeader` returns, the temporary native struct is destroyed. But the MIDI code still has a reference to it. And that's the key point, the MIDI code holds a reference to your struct and needs to be able to access it.

The version with the separately written fields works because that struct is blittable. And so the p/invoke marshaller optimises the call by pinning the managed structure which is binary compatible with the native structure. There's still a window of opportunity for the GC to relocate the struct before you call `midiOutUnprepareHeader` but it seems that you've not been caught out by that yet. Were you to persevere with the bittable struct you would need to pin it until you called `midiOutUnprepareHeader`.

So, the bottom line is that you need to provide a structure that lives until you call `midiOutUnprepareHeader`. Personally, I suggest that you use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, `Marshal.StructureToPtr`, and then `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` once `midiOutUnprepareHeader` returns. And obviously switch the parameters from `ref MidiHeader` to `IntPtr`.

I don't think I need to show you any code because it is clear from your question that you know how to do this stuff. Indeed the solution I propose is one that you've already tried and observed work. But now you know why!